# Export Outlook contact organization info

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010, there a handy feature - organization information, which let you see one's manager or direct reports. Is there a tool or plug-in that can export these info into a spreadsheet? Eventually I would like to use these info to generate a organization chart. How to do this?

Answer (score 6):

There is an Organization Chart Wizard template in Microsoft Viso 2010 [that can export the data out of your Exchange server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-organization-chart-automatically-from-employee-data-8f2e693e-25fc-410e-8264-9084eb0b9360) (or other data sources).

In Microsoft Visio (get a free trial here http://visio.microsoft.com/en-us/TryBuy/TryVisio2010forFree/Pages/Try_Visio_2010_for_Free.aspx)

1. File -> New
2. Template Categories -> Business
3. Organization Chart Wizard

If you have contacts that are not stored in Exchange, or an ODBC-compliant (like Microsoft Access) database, you can follow the instructions here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/export-contacts-HA101870639.aspx to export the contacts and generate a flat file data source.

If you want to export contacts in the Exchange Global Address List from Outlook, as far as I know I don't think it is possible directly through Outlook.  There are ways to do it through external programs such as Access that can access Exchange Server as a connected data source.  See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/access/export-exchange-global-address-list-to-access/

Once you have your export file, it can be used as a data source in the Visio 2010 Organization Chart Wizard template instead of pointing directly at an Exchange Server.